# WoW freezing the second I launch it

Tags: wine, games, freeze

I just installed WoW on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, once I opened it the game froze(it was supposed to play the intro because I have never run it before in this computer).
I have to log off or reboot my computer so that the game closes or else it just stays there frozen. Any suggestions?
I am using Wine 1.7.55

**Edit: Now it won't even open, it will just pop a window telling me to report an error to Blizzard I tried the registry change nothing maybe someone can tell me how to find and Install DirectX 9 or 11 because I have DirectX 6, And that might be the problem.**

Comment: Try creating a new clean wine prefix and moving the WoW directory to this new prefix. Then launch the game. As far as I remember WoW runs OOTB on Wine.

Comment: Maybe my DirectX 9.0 c is too old? Or maybe I need DIrect3D, but haven't found  a way to install a newer version of DirectX or to install Direct3D

Comment: Have a look at the Wine HQ site for WoW, they list some things to do to get it working. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32314 Did you tried a new prefix as I suggested?

Comment: I have no Idea on how to try a new prefix, also note if it requires deleting the wine folder( yeah I am a newbie in ubuntu) I have other apps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try a new prefix.

1. Open a terminal and type `pwd` you will get a line similar to this `/home/username`, take note of this.
2. Type `sudo apt-get install winetricks` to install Winetricks, we will need this tool later
3. Type `WINEPREFIX=/home/YourUser/WoWPrefix winecfg` to create a new prefix. Where it says **YourUser** you write the name we got at step 1.
4. Click *Cancel* to **"Wine Mono Installer"** and **"Wine Gecko Installer"**. When the **"Wine configuration"** window appears set the *Windows Version* to *Windows 7*, then click **OK**.
5. Now, go to your file manager and copy the WoW installation folder to `WoWPrefix/drive_c/Program Files/put it here`. The WoW installation may be at `.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Blizzard/World of Warcraft` if you can't see the `.wine` folder inside your home folder, press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>H</kbd>**. Folders whose name begin with `.` are hidden.
6. You have WoW in a new prefix now! So lets follow the advice given at Wine HQ and install the required components:
7. `WINEPREFIX=/home/YourUser/WoWPrefix winetricks corefonts`
8. Open Wine Config again `WINEPREFIX=/home/YourUser/WoWPrefix winecfg` and navigate to the **Libraries** tab.
9. Copy and paste the following items in the "New override" camp one by one and click "Add": `*msvcr90` `d3dcompiler_46` `dbghelp` `msvcp100`
10. Select them and click *Edit* to set the values to each one to match the following list:

    - `*msvcr90=native,builtin`
    - `d3dcompiler_46=disabled`
    - `dbghelp=native,builtin`
    - `msvcp100=native,builtin`
11. Done, run it! `WINEPREFIX=/home/YourUser/WoWPrefix wine 'WoWPrefix/drive_c/World of Warcraft/Wow.exe'`

Comment: Ok I am trying this now... Now Battle.net app won't launch!*yay* ;-;

Comment: This happens after launching the copy in the new prefix?

Comment: No, it happened from while ago and I don't know why, I am now copying the WoW folder to the prefix

Comment: Nope It doesn't work, maybe because the battle.net app does not work at all? When I run the .exe file the pointer turns to the loading one and then goes back to  normal without anything happening. **Edit: It opened but nothing happened and then crashes ;-;. BTW I have wine 1.7.55**

Comment: Okay, when you launch it, the Terminal shows a lot of stuff, copy all that in the range "launch command" to "crash time" and upload to a pastebin. Lets have a look at the logs.

Comment: It can't find the location wine: cannot find '/home/bill/drive_c/Program Files/World of Warcraft Public Test/WowT.exe'
I launched mannually before

Comment: Well, is WoW installed under that address? `/home/bill/drive_c/Program Files/World of Warcraft Public Test/WowT.exe` Be careful when typing, I don't see mentioned **WoWPrefix** in the line you posted.

Comment: WINEPREFIX=/home/bill/WoWPrefix wine '/home/bill/WoWPrefix/drive_c/Program Files/World of Warcraft Public Test'

Comment: wine: cannot find L"C:\\Program Files\\World of Warcraft Public Test."

Comment: Okay, make sure you copied Battle.net folder and WoW folder, then add the corresponding `.exe` extension to the end of that line and launch it. Tell me how it goes. Yo are having **"not found"** errors, which simply means you are not writing the directions correctly in the command. As a side note, to avoid typing that much, you can drag the file to the terminal, it will automatically write the address for you. `WINEPREFIX=/home/YourUser/WoWPrefix  wine DRAG&DROP.exe`

Comment: check the answer I posted.